# Content of spark's TextArea or RichText

Tags: apache-flex, textarea, richtext, flex-spark

Is it possible to get content of each line from spark's TextArea or RichText?

What I want to achieve it to split textarea's (or richtext) content into rows and modify some of them.

Answer (score 1):

var rows : Array = textArea.text.split ("\n");

Comment: It is not working at all. Try it with text that has no line breaks and as a result you will get exact copy of that text. On the other hand, in TextArea yoo will get multiple lines.